# How to make the provider configuration optional and based on the condition in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure

Here is my provider configuration:

```
provider "azurerm" {

  features {}

        subscription_id = "${var.azure.AzureSubscriptionId}"

        client_id       = "${var.azure.AzureClientId}"

        client_secret   = "${var.azure.AzureClientSecret}"

        tenant_id       = "${var.azure.AzureTenantId}"

        skip_provider_registration = true

}

provider "aws" {

        region     = "${var.aws.AwsRegion}"

        access_key = "${var.aws.AwsAccessKey}"

        secret_key = "${var.aws.AwsSecretKey}"

}
```

and this is how my root module is configured:

```
module "aws_bootstrap_vm" {

      count = var.CloudProvider == "aws" ? 1 : 0
      source = "./modules/aws/bootstrap_vm"
}

module "azure_bootstrap_vm" {

      count = var.CloudProvider == "azure" ? 1 : 0
      source = "./modules/azure/bootstrap_vm"
}
```

Currently I need to provide the credentials for both aws & azure to get this to work or else I get this error when I only want to use the AWS module:

```
 Error: building AzureRM Client: 1 error occurred:
│       * A Subscription ID must be configured when authenticating as a Service Principal using a Client Secret.
│
```

My folder structure looks like this:

```
├───modules
│   ├───aws
│   │   ├───prepare_cloud
│   │   │   ├───config
│   │   │   └───templates
│   │   ├───virtual_network
│   └───azure
│       ├───prepare_cloud
│       │   └───config
│       ├───virtual_network
└───main
```

Comment: Dynamically choosing a provider within a single Terraform configuration is not a typical design. The usual approach is to either use a different configuration for each or to write one configuration that _always_ interacts with both. There is no way to dynamically enable a provider configuration in Terraform.

Comment: The problem with having a different configuration is that you can't have providers within modules using count, for_each or depends_on.

Comment: I have updated my post with the folder structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ***Martin Atkins*** has mentioned in the comments , it is ***not possible*** to ***dynamically configure the providers in terraform*** for now.

As a workaround you can ***call the modules separately configuration files if you are using input variables which the user will be asked to input***. For example , there will be ***two configurations folders one for AWS and one for Azure***.

```
AWS
├───modules
│   ├───aws
│   │   ├───prepare_cloud
│   │   │   ├───config
│   │   │   └───templates
│   │   ├───virtual_network
└───main

Azure
├───modules
|   |───azure
│   |   ├───prepare_cloud
│   |   │   └───config
│   |   ├───virtual_network
└───main
```

#### OR

If you are ***providing the values of all variables*** that are used in the `provider.tf` , then you can ***use your configuration***. So , When you are using that ***both the providers will get initialized*** but as per your requirement ***only the required module will run***.